# if statement based on date paramater

Tags: php, wordpress, date, if-statement

I have a wordpress query that gets posts from a custom post type.  The posts have a custom meta date field.  I would like to put posts that have a dat in the future in a table called "Ongoing" (this part is complete and appears to work well). I would like to put posts with a date in the past in a table called "published".  This is where I am having problems as the if statement seems to show posts even if they have a date that is in the future. I am using if completion date is equal to or greater than start of time, now. for the ongoing posts.  I am using the opposite for the published posts with. Seeing as it is the same but inverted, I don't get why the query pulls in posts from a future date.

What am I doing wrong?

Much thanks in advance

---

ONGOING - working

```
<?php $wp_query_ongoing = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'research', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order' => 'asc' ) ); ?>
            <?php while ( $wp_query_ongoing->have_posts() ) : $wp_query_ongoing->the_post(); //start of the loop ?>

        <?php
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $completion_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, "duration_end", true );
            $publication_date = get_post_meta( $post_id,  "publication_date", true );
        ?>
            <?php if (strtotime($publication_date) >= strtotime("now") || strtotime($completion_date) >= strtotime("now")) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpuf-meta name="_hidden_type"]' ); ?></td>
                <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
    ...
                <td>
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpuf-meta name="duration_end"]'); ?>
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpuf-meta name="publication_date"]'); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; //end of the loop ?>
```

PUBLISHED - not working

```
<?php $wp_query_published = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'research', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order' => 'asc' ) ); ?>
        <?php while ( $wp_query_published->have_posts() ) : $wp_query_published->the_post(); //start of the loop ?>

        <?php
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $completion_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, "duration_end", true );
            $publication_date = get_post_meta( $post_id,  "publication_date", true );
        ?>
            <?php if ( strtotime($publication_date) <= strtotime("now") || strtotime($completion_date) <= strtotime("now")){ ?>

<td>
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpuf-meta name="duration_end"]'); ?>
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpuf-meta name="publication_date"]'); ?>
                </td>
<?php } ?>

        <?php endwhile; //end of the loop ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think through your conditionals.  The one you show for the PUBLISHED is NOT the exact opposite of what you have for ONGOING.

Try this:

```
if(strtotime($publication_date) < strtotime("now") && strtotime($completion_date) < strtotime("now"))
```

Note that each portion of the conditional is exactly the opposite of what is in your ONGOING conditional (I removed the `=`).  Also note that you need to use an AND to join these conditions in this case because if you say either condition must be true to make an item go into ONGOING category, then necessarily BOTH conditions must not be met to fall into the PUBLISHED category.

Per your comment you might want to do something like this for your comparisons:

```
$comparison_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, "duration_end", true );
if (empty($comparison_date )) {
    $comparison_date = get_post_meta( $post_id,  "publication_date", true );
}
$comparison_date = strtotime($comparison_date);
// use this for ONGOING
if ($comparison_date >= time()) {
   ...
}
// use this for PUBLISHED
if ($comparison_date < time()) {
   ...
}
```

You also should STRONGLY consider refactoring this into a single script that can handle either filtering case.  No reason to duplicate all this code.

Comment: OK.... that makes sooo much more sense.  I see that I cant use OR now.  The problem is that I cant use AND.  This is because the post will have either a publication date or a completion date, never both.

Comment: @vincentieo Oh then it seems you simply need to inspect both publication and completion date variables to determine which to use in the conditional, not set up a conditional that relies on both values.

Comment: @vincentieo Take a look at revised post to see how you can possible simplify your logic.

Comment: Ok, that is a lot cleaner.  Thank you Mike, another plus heading your way.